# drag file from file chooser or get path

Tags: terminal, filesystem, ui

Editing a file using text wrangler. Want the path so can pass it to a program in the terminal. Is there an easy way to do this? Don't seem to be able to drag it  nor right click and get info.

I'm not in Finder, but in the file chooser dialog that you see when executing File/Save as.

If there is no way to drag would be nice to be able to right click and get info OR/AND send it to a list of program, one of which could simply copy its full path to the system clipboard.

Comment: Did you try to drag the icon at the top of the TextWrangler window?

Comment: that worked and also saw i can right click there and copy the file name/ path / URL. great. if you think this is a non trivial question maybe you can make your comment an answer and i will accept it. though would have been great if that worked from the system File Chooser too.

Comment: fyi I'm on a desktop no trackpad. do not have track pad options as described here https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4139129?start=0&tstart=0 @patrix

Answer (score 2):

In general you can just drag the icon from the Textmate window title to get hold of the file. If you drag it into a Terminal window, the path will be inserted automatically.

Comment: Textmate means general text editor or is that some other specific app

Comment: It works in most applications actually

Answer (score 1):

There is a plug in that enables to copy a file's path directly from the finder with a right click. You can find it here: 
[Copy path](http://www.macableton.com/features/mac-stuff/minimalist-desktop.html#path)

Comment: great i hope it works in the File save as window too!

Comment: the page does not render. weird as if i view src can see the html, but looks like there are a lot of add on scripts that keep loading ... do you have a direct link the add on and one more to instructions? thank you

Comment: Mmmh, I am sorry about that. I had it installed on my computer and did not check the link to download the script... It is not working anymore. Doing a quick search I found this alternative: http://www.abracode.com/free/cmworkshop/file_utils.html  I don't know this add-on, and cannot try it out right now. But according to the description it allows you to copy a file path in the clipboard with a right click.